# Oracle sql (and Apex) case when in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Can you help me with one conditions with case when in where clause?
I have tried build something like that, but apex interface returned error:

```
where
tmp.employee_name in
(case when :APP_USER = 'xxx.xxx' THEN ('yyy.yyy', 'aaa.aaa')
      when :APP_USER = 'ddd.ddd' THEN ('xxx.xxx', 'uuu.uuu')
end)
```

Apex returned error like: `"ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 17, column 85: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"`
When I used only one value like `THEN ('yyy.yyy')` everything is ok, but I need use few variables.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value and not an expression (or list of expressions).

Instead, use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
WHERE (   :APP_USER = 'xxx.xxx'
      AND tmp.employee_name in ('yyy.yyy', 'aaa.aaa')
      )
OR    (   :APP_USER = 'ddd.ddd'
      AND tmp.employee_name in ('xxx.xxx', 'uuu.uuu')
      )
```

Comment: Ah.. it was so simply.. Thanks a lot, works!